# How wait the end of N process in ksh and after run another process?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, ksh

I want run 3 process at the same time and when ALL 3 process are finished I want run another process.

for example:

./script1.sh &
./script2.sh &

wait that script1 and script2 are finished and after run ./script3

thanks for help

Comment: `s1 & s2 & ; wait; s3`. Good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait (the end of N process in ksh and after run another process) dont work correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113267/wait-the-end-of-n-process-in-ksh-and-after-run-another-process-dont-work-corre)

Answer (score 4):

`man ksh`

```
       wait [ job ... ]
              Wait for the specified job and report  its  termination  status.
              If  job  is not given, then all currently active child processes
              are waited for.
```

So, e. g.

```
./script1.sh& ./script2.sh& ./script3.sh
wait
./script4.sh
```

will do as long as there is no other currently active child process.